# Tuplify the keys types

Tags: typescript, tuples

Is there a way in typescript to do the following:

```
type Foo = {
  code?: string;
  name: string;
  bar: number;
}

let bar: Tuple<Foo>; // a: [string | undefined, string, number]
```

Comment: In a safe, reliable manner with no gotchas or undocumented edge cases no.

Comment: Besides, what's the order of the elements in the tuple? What is the criteria or pattern it follows?

Comment: @kelly it should follows the order of keys

Comment: Key ordering is not meant to be observable in TypeScript so there's nothing that guarantees you will get the order you expect.